# Adding a filter to a gt table for sorting R

Tags: r, datatable, gt

I am looking for a way to add a filter to a gt table that can be used for sorting each column. I have seen similar functionality for data tables, but have been unsuccessful finding an option for gt (possibly because it's a relatively new package). Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible natively with `gt` by adding `opt_interactive()` to your table. See [examples and documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/gt/man/opt_interactive.html).

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, `gt` itself doesn't do any data restructuring but is instead a package that visualizes the table. If you're hoping to do data restructuring, I'd recommend the `dplyr` package which has `arrange` functions that will help you sort the data by multiple columns, and then that can get passed into `gt` neatly.

Alternatively, you can use various base R methods to order your data table before printing: https://www.statmethods.net/management/sorting.html